# Execute command when vim filter command is interrupted

Tags: linux, vim

I use filter commands in vim to call bash scripts that I need to interrupt sometimes. I do this by hitting Ctrl+C in the vim window. The bash script terminates then (at least vim stops the filter command) but the text I passed to the filter command (usually a visual selection) will be missing. I would like vim to return to the state before the filter command if I interrupt execution by Ctrl+C or the bash script finishes with exit state other than 0. Note that I know that I can press u to undo, but I would like to modify the filter command to do this since I could forget to press u and loose the text without noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set signal and/or exit handlers in bash. `man bash`, `/trap.*sigspec`

Something like:

```
trap "your_commands"  SIGINT
my_program
```

To make it "preserve" the text, you probably need something like that:

```
TIN=`mktemp`
TOUT=`mktemp`
cat > $TIN
trap "cat $TIN; rm -f $TIN; rm -f $TOUT" EXIT
do_something < $TIN > $TOUT || cp $TIN $TOUT
mv $TOUT $TIN
```

Checked in my Vim, seems to be working. (tested with `sed` and `sleep` as do_something)

Comment: Nice trick though 1. it has to be `do_something < /tmp/text.txt` to preserve current behavior 2. it has to be `if do_something </tmp/text.txt >/tmp/out.txt ; then cat /tmp/out.txt ; else cat /tmp/text.txt ; endif ; rm -f /tmp/{text,out}.txt` to suffice the “or the bash script finishes with exit status other then 0” part and 3. you ought to be using `mktemp` here.

Comment: @mikezter, You can write your implementation, like `mktemp() { echo /tmp/$$_$RANDOM; }`